# Accessing object's property inside array Javascript AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of products, each product has a price. I want to create a filter to calculate the total price of all products. The problem is that I can't use *forEach()* since I'm in a callback function. My question is, is there a function that does something like *myArray.(intheobject).price*, or a way to manage the callback and get the right results?

```
this.productList = [
    {
      type: 'chocolate',
      pack: '3',
      price: 5,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'chocolate',
      pack: '5',
      price: 7,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'chocolate',
      pack: '10',
      price: 10,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'honey',
      pack: '3',
      price: 5,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'honey',
      pack: '5',
      price: 7,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'honey',
      pack: '10',
      price: 10,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'candy',
      pack: '3',
      price: 5,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'candy',
      pack: '5',
      price: 7,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'candy',
      pack: '10',
      price: 10,
      checkState: false
    }
  ]


.filter('calculateTotal', function(){
  var totalCost = 0;
  return function(input){
    return totalCost + ???
  }    
})
```

After [PierreDuc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3106920/pierreduc)'s answer, my filter is this:

```
.filter('calculateTotal', function(){
  return function(input){
    return input.reduce((total, item) => item.price + total, 0);
  }    
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method for this:

```
const totalPrice = [{
    type: 'chocolate',
    pack: '3',
    price: 5,
    checkState: false
  },
  {
    type: 'chocolate',
    pack: '5',
    price: 7,
    checkState: false
}].reduce((total, item) => item.price + total, 0);
```

Filter is used to, like the name suggests, filter the current array based on a the return value of the provided method.

With reduce you can transform your array based on an input, `0` in this case. This gets assigned to the `total` parameter of the passed method, where the `item` is every item in your array. The value you return from that method will be the new value for the `total` parameter.

Comment: Thanks you for you quick reply I had been trying to figure this out for a couple hours. I have updated my post with the modified correct filter.

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` callback can access each element. So you need to create a global variable, outside the callback function and add the value of each element in the callback function to that global variable. See [filter documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

```
this.totalCost = 0;

this.productList = [
    {
      type: 'chocolate',
      pack: '3',
      price: 5,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'chocolate',
      pack: '5',
      price: 7,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'chocolate',
      pack: '10',
      price: 10,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'honey',
      pack: '3',
      price: 5,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'honey',
      pack: '5',
      price: 7,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'honey',
      pack: '10',
      price: 10,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'candy',
      pack: '3',
      price: 5,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'candy',
      pack: '5',
      price: 7,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'candy',
      pack: '10',
      price: 10,
      checkState: false
    }
  ]
var self = this;
angular.module('myReverseFilterApp', [])
.filter('calculateTotal', function(){
      return function(input) {
           self.totalCost += input.price;
      }
})
```

You can then access the `totalCost` variable in your html. It is not possbile to return the `totalCost` from a filter function becaus this function gets applied to each element of the array. It is possible that the syntax is not correct, but I guess you get the gist.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const productList = [
    {
      type: 'chocolate',
      pack: '3',
      price: 5,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'chocolate',
      pack: '5',
      price: 7,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'chocolate',
      pack: '10',
      price: 10,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'honey',
      pack: '3',
      price: 5,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'honey',
      pack: '5',
      price: 7,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'honey',
      pack: '10',
      price: 10,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'candy',
      pack: '3',
      price: 5,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'candy',
      pack: '5',
      price: 7,
      checkState: false
    },
    {
      type: 'candy',
      pack: '10',
      price: 10,
      checkState: false
    }
  ]
let totalPrice = productList.reduce(function(sum, currentValue, currentIndex, array) {
  return sum+currentValue['price']
},0);
console.log(totalPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as following, First get the list of all the prices and store it in an array, and then use the reduce function to perform the action on prices
also read the documentation of reduce function:

[reduce documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
let pricesList = [];
productList.forEach(product => {

    pricesList.push(product['price']);

})

let sumPrice = pricesList.reduce((priceA, priceB) => priceA + priceB, 0);
```

Comment: That's some extra code that could be avoided. My question has been answered, if you check I have already updated my post with the provided answer.